# Partition is gone and C: is smaller

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

My computer restarted overnight to install windows update. In the morning I had tried to make a System Restore (Windows restore to a point) as my video driver got messed up. I also reinstalled some video drivers.

When I noticed, one of my partitions was gone

[image: partition]

[image: hd]

I had a partition called `S:` of about ~300gb. Now `C:` is smaller than it should be (shows that can store 600gb) but on the `C:` partition it shows 900gb+...

What could have happened? How can I restore my partition `S:`?

Comment: try to look for a "Partition Recovery" software... it can search partition on the disk and may be able to restore it. (as soon as nothing wrote on it)

Comment: "I had tried to make a System Restore" Can you explain exactly what you mean by this? What did you do exactly?

Comment: It’s GB, by the way. Please be careful, it’s important not to make errors like that when modifying the disk. Setting that aside, did you do a Windows System Restore or did you execute the OEM recovery process?

Comment: Windows system restore

Comment: Windows Update didn't delete the partition.  Something else happend that triggered the lost of the partition.  Since significant amount of data has already been written again because of the attempt to use a restoration point its unlikely data recovery will be possible but you can always try.

Comment: I think it's not system restore. you have run system recovery and because of this your system is in original purchased state now. are you able to find installed softwares ?